# why magento using other product's url key for url rewrite

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.7

I am using `magento 1.7`. i am faceing strange problem. `magento` making duplicate product url with random number with wrong url key please my attached screenshot

I also empty table `rewrite_urls` and reindex urls but still i am getting wrong urls. please help me to solve this problem. if you are unable to view images in question then please click on links [duplicate product urls](https://www.diigo.com/item/image/3se7l/qu5h) and [Product in admin panel](https://www.diigo.com/item/image/3se7l/hdve?size=o)

[image: Duplicate product urls],[image: actual product]

Let me make understand u with example

Like i have one product named "example" and url key is "example" Url will be

```
www.example.com/example
```

and now i have created new product "xyz and  url key is "xyz" and url should be

```
www.example.com/xyz
```

but magento generating url

```
www.example.com/example-123
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in 1.7.
If you have multiple simple products with the same url key as the configurable product (e.g. all names are the same), than magento always creates a new url rewrite on every index process.
Example:

First index:

- myproducturl (config product)
- myproducturl-id (simple product with its id appended, so far so good)

Second index:

- myproducturl (config product)
- myproducturl-randomnumber (simple product with random number, BAD)
- myproducturl-id --> myproducturl-randomnumber (rewrite to the new url)

And on every new index process the last step will be repeated, so always a new random url key is generated.
If magento would check, that a url key with the id for that product already exists, this should be no problem.

After a few months, you will have a really big url_rewrite table, because nothing will be deleted and on every run, at least 1 record for every product with the same url key will be created.

Comment: I am agree with you Chris, but did you get solution of this problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to eliminate the extra numbers at the end of the URLs by truncating the table "core_url_rewrites" (I made sure to make copy first) then reindexed it.